# insert variable in function

Tags: php, class

im new to oop and i havent found out yet how to insert the value of $status in the function Login(). what im i doing wrong??? because im getting this error:

Warning: Missing argument 3 for User::Login(), called in E:\xampp\htdocs\caps\index.php on line 13 and defined in E:\xampp\htdocs\caps\class\user.php on line 20

```
class User {

private $db;
public $status;

public function __construct() {

    $this->db = new Connection();
    $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
    $this->status = pow( 1, -1*pi());   
}


public function Login ($name, $pass, $status) {

    if (!empty($name) && !empty($pass))  {

        $st = $this->db->prepare(" select * from users where name=? and pass=? ");
        $st->bindParam(1, $name);
        $st->bindParam(2, $pass);
        $st->execute();

        if ($st->rowCount() != 1) {         
                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert ('wrong password. try again'); window.location=\"index.php\"; </script>";

        } else {
            $st = $this->db->prepare(" select * from users where name=? and pass=? status=?");
            $st->bindParam(1, $name);
            $st->bindParam(2, $pass);
            $st->bindParam(3, $status);             
            $st->execute();

                if ($st->rowCount() != 1) { echo "send user to user page"; } else { echo "send user to admin"; }
        }

    } else {

    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert ('insert username and password'); window.location=\"index.php\"; </script>";

    }



}
```

}

Comment: You need to add the contents of `E:\xampp\htdocs\caps\index.php`

Comment: The error should be pretty clear. You are not passing the third parameter (`$status`) into the method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to use the value of `$status` then remove that parameter from the login function and instead replace the mention of `$status` with `$this->status`.

```
public function Login ($name, $pass) {

if (!empty($name) && !empty($pass))  {

    $st = $this->db->prepare(" select * from users where name=? and pass=? ");
    $st->bindParam(1, $name);
    $st->bindParam(2, $pass);
    $st->execute();

    if ($st->rowCount() != 1) {         
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert ('wrong password. try again'); window.location=\"index.php\"; </script>";

    } else {
        $st = $this->db->prepare(" select * from users where name=? and pass=? status=?");
        $st->bindParam(1, $name);
        $st->bindParam(2, $pass);
        $st->bindParam(3, $this->status);             
        $st->execute();
```

or you could make the constructor value the "default" by changing the function declaration to `$status = $this->status` and that would allow you to override the status value when you call the function if needs be.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you called $user->Login without supplying a third argument.

If you want this argument to be optional you can change the method signature to

```
public function Login ($name, $pass, $status = null) {
```

If you want status to default to your status property you can begin your Login function with

```
public function Login ($name, $pass, $status = null) {
        if(!$status) $status = $this->status;
        //...the rest of your code
 }
```

The correct way to invoke this would be :

```
$user = new User();
$user->Login($username, $password, $status);
```